# Installing Xamarin Studio with Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin

I am trying to install ***Xamarin*** on my PC. I have downloaded ***Xamarin*** Studio but am not able to get it to work with Visual Studio 2015.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to download Xamarin for Visual Studio, not just Xamarin Studio.

You should be able to get the Xamarin for Visual Studio installer via your Xamarin account here: https://store.xamarin.com/account/my/subscription/downloads

Click the `Hide all versions` link under the blue button, then pick one of the Windows links under Xamarin.iOS or Xamarin.Android to download the installer you need.

Once you install that, you should be ready to work in Visual Studio.